# I am using ngx-datepicker in my project where I get date value in form control as 2018-06-29T07:46 :44.000Z instead of DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

After selecting date from ngx-datepicker in Input box it shows properly DD/MM/YYYY but in form value its in another format  2018-06-29T07:46 :44.000Z

Comment: Well, you can use Angular DatePipe for that. [Here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) is the link with relevant code samples.

Answer (score 0):

This is called timestamp, it is used as a standard format of time, make a filter/service to convert it to your desired format by this code

```
GetFormattedDate() {
  const todayTime = new Date();
  const month = format(todayTime.getMonth() + 1);
  const day = format(todayTime.getDate());
  const year = format(todayTime.getFullYear());
  const final = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
  console.log(final);
}
```

Or additionally , you can use moment library, which can do things for you, I hope ngx-datepicker must have the moment library just look for the appropriate function and use it.

https://momentjs.com/